# How to interpret the numeric values for "height" in a dendrogram using Ward's clustering method

Tags: hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, ward

I am a biology student investigating a new method of creating a dichotomous identification key.  I have created a dendrogram using data I have collected from a survey on how people rate how similar pictures of plant leaves are.  I used ward's method to link the clusters.  In the resulting dendrogram, I have a y-axis that ranges between 0 and about 50.  I know that this axis represents at which the objects are joined in a cluster, thus how far they are from other objects, but I was wondering what exactly does the numeric value represent?
[image]

Comment: Do you have a reference for this graph?

Comment: Please read the documentation for the clustering program you used.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to, ahem, go out on a limb here, ahem, and guess that you built your tree via the `hclust` function in base R with `method = "ward.D2"`, which is Ward's original method. If you type `?hclust` and look for `height` in the `value` (output) section, it says "The clustering height: that is, the value of the criterion associated with the clustering method for the particular agglomeration." In this case, Ward's criterion [is the total within-cluster error sum of squares](http://homes.mpimf-heidelberg.mpg.de/~mhelmsta/pdf/1963%20Ward%20JASA.pdf), which increases as you go up the tree and make the clusters bigger.